# How to get Mathematica to carry out my computation of a vector norm fully?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector

I am relatively new to Mathematica, and I have come across the problem where Mathematica often doesn't seem to carry out calculations fully. For example: I have a vector v and want to find its norm, which I do as follows:

```
ω = Exp[2 π  I/Sqrt[n]]
θ = ArcCos[1/2(Cos[2πkx / Sqrt[n]]+Cos[2πky /Sqrt[n]])]

v = (1/4Cos[θ/2])*{-(ω^kx(1+ω^ky),-(1+ω^ky),ω^ky(1+ω^kx),(1+ω^kx)}
Norm[v]
```

(Note that `kx` and `ky` are variables, while `n` is a constant).

The output is a very long and complicated expression containing `Abs[ ]`, even though from manual calculations I know that the norm of this vector is in fact 1. I don't understand why Mathematica does not actually carry out the calculations? I have encountered this problem a few times now.

Comment: It's dangerous to use `Underscript` to define rational expressions in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Symbolic is not a simple business. You can complete it as follows

```
vv = v0*{-ω^kx (1 + ω^ky), -(1 + ω^ky), ω^ky (1 + ω^kx), (1 + ω^kx)}

FullSimplify[(Simplify[Norm[vv] // ComplexExpand // TrigToExp, 
     Assumptions -> {Element[n, Integers], n > 0}] // 
    PowerExpand) /. {v0 -> 1/(4 Cos[θ/2])}]
```

(* 1 *)

Don't forget to input ω and
θ before these computations.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code (without `Underscript`,change `cos` to Cos` )

```
ω = Exp[2 π  I/Sqrt[n]]
θ = ArcCos[1/2 (Cos[ 2 π kx/Sqrt[n]] + Cos[ 2 π ky/Sqrt[n]] )]

v = 1/(4 Cos[θ/2]) *{- ω^kx (1 + ω^ky), -(1 + ω^ky), ω^ky (1 + ω^kx), (1 + ω^kx)}
Norm[v] // ComplexExpand
```

Last expression gives a huge expression!

Comment: But why does it give a huge expression? I know that the norm is 1, so why can't Mathematica calculate that?

Comment: Check your  expressions. Are  parameters `kx,ky` correct or did you mean `k x,k y`?

Comment: Yes, I meant kx and ky